# what's the best library to display 3d stuff in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

Say I have an array of point coordinates in a 3d space, like

> point1 x=5, y=10, z=15
>
> point2 x=1, y=25, z=3
>
> ... and so on.

And I need to show them in a sort of a 3d environment, where the user would be able to zoom in, pan and rotate, in a winform.

I haven't done 3d in c# before, so I wanted to ask what's the method/library of choice for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start here: Viewport3D Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewport3d.aspx

You have to program the zoom/pan by your self, but there are probably many examples how to.